# How to invoke exe in powershell while writing to host & get the exit code

Tags: powershell

I have some PowerShell code (below) and am getting the output from the file by piping to `Out-Host`.

I also need to get the error integer value and return it from my script to determine if there was an error in a larger process.

How do I pipe the output AND get the error code?

```
if (Test-Path ".\bin\Release\Analytics.MappingMigration.exe")
{
    $code = (& ".\bin\Release\Analytics.MappingMigration.exe ." 2>&1 | Out-Host)
    Write-Host $code
    Pause
    exit $code
}
```

Comment: `$lastexitcode` I think.

Comment: oh nice, global variable. Seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the automatic variable `$lastexitcode` immediately after the executable call.

> **$lastExitCode**
>
> A number that represents the exit code/error level of
>   the last script or application that exited
>
> - https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/windows-powershell-cookbook/9780596528492/ch01s11.html